# Need an anchor tag to download a binary file inside a td table cell

Tags: javascript, html, webview, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to achieve something like I've shown in the image.

When an user clicks on that anchor tag, a fileselector should appear and binary (.bin) file has to get downloaded in the location where user selects. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGhw1.png)

I've created 'a' tag, and set all the attributes like 'download', 'filename' etc.
But, I'm not able to download it. I'm implementing it in a webview of VSCode extension.

I don't want to post the complete code as previously question got closed due to some confusion. So, please help me with the ways/code to achieve this from scratch. Thanks in advance.

here is the code snippet:

```
function buildTable() {
let tableDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('table-container')[0];
let data = pagination(state.querySet, state.page, state.rows);
let rows = data.trimmedData;
if (rows.length === 0) {
    tableDiv.style.display = 'none';
    return;
}

if (rows.length > 0) {
    tableDiv.style.display = 'block';
    let tableHead = document.getElementById('table-head');
    let tableBody = document.getElementById('table-body');
    // let head = "";
    tableBody.innerHTML = "";
    tableHead.innerHTML = "";
    let keys = state.columnHeaders;
    noOfCols = keys.length;
    noOfRows = 0;
    
    keys.forEach(key => {
        let thEl;
        console.log("table header is", tableHead);
        thEl = document.createElement('th');
        thEl.innerText = key;
        console.log("table header is", tableHead);
        // head += "<th>" + key + "</th>";
        console.log("keys are", keys);
        // tableHead.innerHTML = head;
        tableHead.appendChild(thEl);
    });
    
    console.log("rows are", rows);
    console.log("table body is", tableBody);
    rows.forEach((row) => {
        noOfRows++;
        let trEl = document.createElement('tr');
        console.log("table row is", trEl);
        // body += `<tr id="element${noOfRows}">`;
        trEl.setAttribute('id', `element${noOfRows}`);

        //body += "<tr>";
        console.log("each row is", row);
        keys.forEach((key, index) => {   
            console.log("row of key is", row[key]);
            const tdEl = document.createElement('td');
            if(row[key] === undefined){
                // body += `<td>NULL</td>`;
                tdEl.innerText = "NULL";
                trEl.appendChild(tdEl);
            }
            else{
                if(row[key] === null){
                    // body += `<td>null</td>`;
                    tdEl.innerText = "null";
                    trEl.appendChild(tdEl);
                }
                else if (fieldTypes[index] === columnTypes.JSON || basicTypes[index] === "ARRAY" || basicTypes[index] === "MAP" || basicTypes[index] === "RECORD") {
                    const text = JSON.stringify(row[key], undefined, 10);
                    // body += "<td>" + text + "</td>";
                    tdEl.innerText = text;
                    trEl.appendChild(tdEl);
                } else if (fieldTypes[index] === "BINARY") {
                    const colID = index;
                    const rowID = noOfRows-1;
                    const binaryVal = row[key];
                    console.log("value from db is", binaryVal);
                    var len = binaryVal.length;
                    var arr = new Uint8Array(len);
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        arr[i] = binaryVal.charCodeAt(i);
                    }
                    console.log("array is", arr);

                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    // var blob = new Blob([binaryVal], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
                    // var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    // a.target = '_blank';
                    // a.click();
                    a.href = 'application/octet-stream,' + encodeURI(binaryVal);
                    // a.target = '_blank';
                    // a.href = url;
                    a.download = `row-${rowID}-${colID}.bin`;
                    a.textContent = "Download Binary Object";
                    a.click();
                    tdEl.appendChild(a);
                    trEl.appendChild(tdEl);
                    
                    // body += `<td> <a href=${url} download="binaryObject.bin"><div style="height:100%;width:100%"> Download Binary Object </div></a> </td>`;
                } else {
                    // body += "<td>" + row[key] + "</td>";
                    tdEl.innerText = row[key];
                    trEl.appendChild(tdEl);
                }
                console.log("table row is", trEl);
            }   
        });
        
       // body.appendChild(trEl);
       tableBody.appendChild(trEl);
       console.log("table body is", tableBody);
        
    });
    
    // tableBody.innerHTML = body;
    setpageButtons(data.pages);
    enableTableContentListeners();
}
```

}

Comment: We still need a proper [mre] of the issue, it makes little sense to speculate about code we don't even get shown.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community I have added the code snippet. Please have a look